# scaling problem with rigify when using multiple objects

Tags: armature, bones, rigify

I am having an issue where when i move any of the rigify armature bones, the objects are being scaled up, as seen here:
[image]

I am using individual objects for each bone that is parented to the armature by bone as to not bend them.

I would like it if the objects didn't scale up every time i move the bone out of range and for the armature to be limited to the current scale of the object, as you would have if using one object with the rig.

If anyone has a solution, it would very much help when it comes to posing and animating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your rig, go to pose mode and select the IK control.

In N-panel > Item > Rig Main properties set IK stretch to 0.
[image]